# How to use s3 LifecycleRule tag_filters in python AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

In AWS CDK with Python, how do you use the `tag_filters` parameter of `aws_s3.LifecycleRule`?

Here is a link to the documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_s3/LifecycleRule.html#aws_cdk.aws_s3.LifecycleRule

The documentation has no examples of how to actually provide tags inside of tag_filters.

Here are some of the things I've tried:

###### Attempt

```
                s3.LifecycleRule(
                    id="1 Day TTL",
                    expiration=core.Duration.days(1),
                    tag_filters=[
                        "time_to_expire_days=1"
                    ]
                ),
```

Produces the tag `0: time_to_expire_days=1`

###### Attempt

```
                s3.LifecycleRule(
                    id="1 Day TTL",
                    expiration=core.Duration.days(1),
                    tag_filters=[
                        "time_to_expire_days", 
                        "1"
                    ]
                ),
```

Produces the tag `0: time_to_expire_days, 1: 1`

###### Attempt

```
                s3.LifecycleRule(
                    id="1 Day TTL",
                    expiration=core.Duration.days(1),
                    tag_filters=[
                        { 'Key': 'string', 'Value': 'string'  }
                    ]
                ),
```

Doesn't compile

###### Attempt

```
                s3.LifecycleRule(
                    id="1 Day TTL",
                    expiration=core.Duration.days(1),
                    tag_filters=[
                        "{ 'Key': 'string', 'Value': 'string'  }"
                    ]
                ),
```

Produces the tag `0: { 'Key': 'string', 'Value': 'string' }`

###### Attempt

```
                s3.LifecycleRule(
                    id="1 Day TTL",
                    expiration=core.Duration.days(1),
                    tag_filters=[
                        "time_to_expire_days: 1"
                    ]
                ),
```

Produces the tag `0: time_to_expire_days: 1`

Any thoughts on what else I could try? I can't figure it out from the docs and I can't find any examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

The answer was... RTFM.

I went back and more carefully read the docs. tag_filters are described as `(Optional[Mapping[str, Any]])` . Referencing other working code described this way, I came to the correct solution.

#### Here is the working code:

```
                s3.LifecycleRule(
                    id="1 Day TTL",
                    expiration=core.Duration.days(1),
                    tag_filters={ 
                        'Key': 'time_to_expire_days', 
                        'Value': '1' 
                    }
                ),
```

#### Screenshot from S3

[image]